# What's wrong with how I'm declaring this Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, object, declaration

I have an object called TruckModel which is defined earlier in my JavaScript file called milktruck.js

I'm trying to create an array of these TruckModel objects because I don't know at any given time how many TruckModel objects will be needed as players of my multiplayer game enter and exit.

I know that my current code isn't working because the model won't display when I use the teleportToThat function below.

I was able to get the model to display by declaring only one TruckModel() object in my index.html file and then using the teleportToThat

Here's my code for this, do you see any errors in how I'm doing it?

Non-working version:

```
 var opponentTrucks = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

      opponentTrucks[i] = new TruckModel();
      opponentTrucks[i].teleportToThat( lat, lng, heading );

 }
```

Working version: (Difference being that I'm trying to have a varying amount of TruckModel objects)

Declared in index.html file:

```
 var model;
```

Declared in JavaScript file:

```
 model.teleportToThat( lat, lng, heading );
```

Here's the entire JavaScript file:

http://thehobbit2movie.com/milktruck.js

Comment: Please add a description of how and why you know this to be erroneous.

Comment: Added, should be a bit more descriptive now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to find the objects by numeric index, you want an **array**, not a plain object:

```
var opponentTrucks = [];
```

What you've got will work, kind-of, but there's no reason not to use a real array if you're going to treat it like one anyway.

*edit* — it's still not really clear exactly what the problem is.  This line here:

```
opponentTrucks[i].teleportToThat( lat, lng, heading );
```

What is that supposed to do?  Where is it called from?  What's the value of "i"?  If you simply have that statement following the loop, then it's not going to work.  If you want to have that "teleportToThat()" function called for *each one in the array*, then you should put the function call *inside* the "for" loop.

Comment: That still didn't fix it. I don't have error messages to give, but I know it doesn't work because the model never shows up.

Comment: Well it would have been helpful if you'd said originally that the code does not work.  However, the code (either with my change or not) that you posted is not likely to be the problem.

Comment: Ok, I've added more description now.

Comment: Sorry, yeah it's supposed to be in the for loop I just messed up typing the code on this site. The teleportToThat fuction takes the TruckModel object and teleports/displays the model at the new lat, lng, heading coordinates.

Comment: OK, well in that code right there, I see no problems at all.  What is it that does not work?  In other words, what's making you think that there's a problem, and why do you think it's with this code?

Comment: I think there's a problem because the teleportToThat function doesn't work. The model never appears. I believe it has to do with the way the code is because I can get it to work without using an array and just using the object.

Comment: Well have you tried debugging it?  Like, with Firebug or the Chrome debugger?  That part of the code looks fine to me.

Comment: I've tried debugging with Firebug, but it doesn't seem to help. Every time I try Firebug crashes. I believe this is because there are too many components for Firebug to separate and analyze.

Comment: @user671891 that seems highly unlikely. You could try Chrome, or you could just pepper your code with "console.log()" messages to trace what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only using numeric keys, you want an array, rather than an object:

```
var opponentTrucks = [];

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
     opponentTrucks.push(new TruckModel());
}
```

This probably wouldn't stop your code actually working, but it would almost certainly be an improvement.

If there are still errors, perhaps you could say what they are :-)

Comment: That still didn't fix it. I don't have error messages to give, but I know it doesn't work because the model never shows up.